# sometimes Sitemap model is returning ordered list by discarding numbered items [pages, structure group]

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.5, sites-9.1, dxa-1.8

I am using web 8.5 with dxa 1.5
with in tridion publications there are numbered items [pages, structure groups] to create navigation items like top menu, secondary nav etc.
for that we are using sitemap model.

but same sitemap model has returned correct order of listed items for top menu but for secondary nav order of items got sorted [1st all structure groups then all pages]

**top menu list items:**
[image]

In the above image lst has started with a page then structure groups as per numbers present in the cms.

**secondary menu list items:**
[image]

in the above image list has been taken for secondary nav where list is much in sorted order. starts with all structure groups and then all pages.

It has just ignored all numbering.

**Note**: I have tried this with DXA 1.8 with sites 9.1 and got same behavior.

Comment: Please check the published `navigation.json` (the rendered output of the _Navigation Page).

Comment: For static (SG-based) navigation, the entire Navigation Model (Sitemap) is generated on CM-side in this TBB (note it sorts the items on CM Title, including sequence prefixes): https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/1.8/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates/Templates/GenerateSitemap.cs

Comment: BTW: `TmscSitemapItem` is a customized class. DXA Framework must have been modified to deserialize this class instead of the standard `SitemapItem`. Maybe that is where the problem lies?

Comment: @RickPannekoek: thank you very much for pointing out the problem area. indeed deserialize is happening but post that json has been stored in cache. that is where the list is getting sorted.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. Please Answer your own Question (for the record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RickPannekoek: thank you very much for pointing out the problem area.

indeed deserialize is happening and post that order of list was correct. but post that json has been stored in cache for better performance. that is where the list is getting sorted.

as an workaround as of now we have commented the code so-that json has not stored in cache.

Comment: For clarity: we’re talking customized code here, right? Not standard DXA Framework?

Comment: @RickPannekoek: yes its customized code. nothing to do with DXA